# Disable PowerPoint features using C#

Tags: c#, powerpoint

My scenario:
          I have a requirement in my project(C#).I need to give the user only reading capability for my powerpoint presentation opened thru my application.All other featues like cut,copy,paste,save,saveas,print,right click context menus should be disabled.How can i achieve this in powerpoint  programatically using c#? can anyone extend their help?

Comment: I don't think that requirement can be implemented. Even if you take drastic measures, such as serving raw pixels using Flash or Silverlight, nothing prevents the user from taking screenshots of your presentation and running an OCR program on the resulting images.

Comment: just wanted to follow up to see if the below answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Can you publish the *ppt* as *pps* and use that file instead?

Comment: nothing stops the user from launching powerpoint first, then file->open choose your .pps and edit it to their heart's content. Saving a presentation as a power point show does not necessarily mean users can't cut,copy,paste,save,saveas,print,right click context menus etc...

Comment: @Peter, true, but I thought OP will open the ppt/pps using his program and hence hide the location of the file. Otherwise, if the user can physically access the file, this question will be meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

Just export each slide as a JPG or PNG and display those: [`Slide.Export`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb251164.aspx). This would be for static slide views. If you want to retain animations, transitions, video/audio and navigation features for your PPT/PPTX, a PowerPoint-to-Flash converter is a better way to do this. iSpring makes a free version of their converter: www.ispringfree.com.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Powerpoint COM component, kind of like whats described here...
[Using C# to display powerpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217890/using-c-to-display-powerpoint)
I have only used Word and Excel ones, and i must say they are extremely easy to use.

Or is you MUST make it completely read-only, id suggest writing your own ODF parser, or investigating in the ODF COM component, maybe that could work as well :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a low number of powerpoint presentations, you can look into [Information Rights Management](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/CH001041006.aspx)  or use the [Permissions Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb230561%28office.12%29.aspx). (Disclaimer:I have not used this)

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to use something like [Aspose.Slides](http://www.aspose.com/categories/product-family-packs/aspose.slides-product-family/default.aspx) to render the Slides to TIFF or PDF and then display those inside your application.

Comment: Latest versions of PowerPoint can save direct to PDF

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using Powerpoint Automation. Get hold of the PowerPoint.Application object and then loop through the CommandBars property and for each command bar, set Visible to false.

This should remove the command bars at least. And there might be other properties on the Application object that lets you disable context menus, but I've never really used powerpoint, so I'm not sure which ones.

I don't think that there's any good way of disabling printing etc altogether though. However, this MS KB article discusses a hacky way of dismissing any dialogs automatically, so assuming that the print/save etc would always bring up a dialog (which I'm not sure off) you might be able to use something from there: [How To Dismiss a Dialog Box Displayed by an Office Application with Visual Basic](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/259971/en-us?spid=2522&sid=72)

It's all VB code in that article, but the ideas will be similar.