# I need to show excel sheet and ppt file in Wpf control without installing MS office

Tags: c#, wpf

I tried with

1. Webbrowser Control:

   When i give the url of file to Webbrowser control of Wpf, it opens the file 
    using MS office.
   Code Snippet: `webbrowser1.Navigate(new Uri(@"D:\ExcelFiles\data.xls");`

   ---
2. DocumentViewer:

   It requires `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll` to achieve.

   ---

I dont want to use MS office or any other installed application to display. Want to render it in any control of WPF only.
So i have to use OpenSource dll to achieve it.

I used `spire.DocViewer.Wpf.dll` to render word document ([WordDoc viewer](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.DocViewer/Spire.DocViewer-Program-Guide/How-to-Open-and-Close-Word-Files-using-Spire.DocViewer.html)).  Like wise, i need to display excelsheet and ppt files.

Please suggest any open source dll to achieve this.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please review the following post and update the question appropriately:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using C# to display powerpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217890/using-c-sharp-to-display-powerpoint)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: Thank u for your suggestion on powerpoint viewer. Please suggest for to view Excel file.

Comment: I tried GemBox.Spreadsheet.dll, its displaying words and  numbers but not charts and pictures in excel sheet.  Please suggest to view Excel file with using Open Source dll.